# do the sin and cos from the columns of a data set

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have data of size (999,100)

I am trying to plot the `sin` and `cos` for each column and plot it as 999 lines in a 3d plot

I have written the code

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(4.3,4))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    tgrid = np.arange(0,999)

    ax.plot3D(tgrid,np.cos(data[:,:100]), np.sin(data[:,:100]), '-',color='black',linewidth=1.5,label='True')

    ax.set_xlabel(r'$t$')
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$\cos(\theta)$')
    ax.set_zlabel(r'$\sin(\theta)$')
    plt.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':12})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    ax.plot3D(tgrid,np.cos(data[:,:100]), np.sin(data[:,:100]), '-',color='black',linewidth=1.5,label='True')
  File "/home/linot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1538, in plot
    zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, len(xs))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in broadcast_to
  File "/home/linot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 182, in broadcast_to
    return _broadcast_to(array, shape, subok=subok, readonly=True)
  File "/home/linot/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 127, in _broadcast_to
    op_flags=['readonly'], itershape=shape, order='C')
ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping
```

I have also tried the following, but it is not saving the figures

```
    data_x=np.cos(data[:,:])
    data_y=np.sin(data[:,:])

    tgrid = np.arange(0,999)
  

    plt.figure(figsize=(4.3,4))
    for jj in range(100):
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        ax.plot3D(tgrid,data_x[jj,:], data_y[jj,:])
        
    plt.savefig('data.pdf')
```

Comment: I have tried the next code, but it is not saving the figures

```
    data_x=np.cos(data[:,:])
    data_y=np.sin(data[:,:])

    tgrid = np.arange(0,999)
  

    plt.figure(figsize=(4.3,4))
    for jj in range(10):
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        ax.plot3D(tgrid,data_x[jj,:], data_y[jj,:])
        
    plt.savefig('data.pdf')

```

Comment: Please don't put code into a comment.  Intead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74967135/edit) your post and add any useful extra information.

Comment: Note that you should put `ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')` outside the `for` loop to avoid the subplot is created again and again for each `jj`.

Comment: You could try `ax.plot3D(np.tile(tgrid, 100), np.cos(data[:, :100]).flatten(), np.sin(data[:, :100]).flatten())` to plot everything in one go.

Comment: I suggest you add enough code that it can run on its own. Your current code doesn't define the `data` variable.

Comment: The issue here is that `tgrid` has shape `(999,) `, but you say your data has shape `(999, 100)`, and `plot3D` is not able to broadcast those two together like the 2d plot is. Just iterate over your data or build an appropriately shaped `tgrid`. For instance, this might do what you need:
`for d in data:
    ax.plot3D(tgrid, np.cos(d), np.sin(d), '-',color='black',linewidth=1.5,label='True')`